# How to change the keybindings of atom add-ons?

Tags: atom-editor, key-bindings

I have installed the atom-shortcuts add-on in Atom, but I can't use the shortcut to toggle the cheatsheet because of my keyboard layout, so I would like to change the keybinding for this add-on but I can't find it by name in the keybindings section of Atom. Where can I find the information necessary to change the keybinding of this add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this particular package is that it doesn't follow the standard way to assign keybindings, i.e. by providing a CSON (or JSON) file inside the `/keymaps` subfolder. Instead, the package assigns the keybinding [programmatically](https://github.com/olegberman/atom-shortcuts/blob/0f197c430c8b544ed603cc89cef4f75b2bad43d2/lib/atom-shortcuts.coffee#L21-L32). It also does not register commands that are triggered by keybindings in its `activate()` method.

Unfortunately, that's a combination that makes it impossible to re-assign keybindings the *“Atom way”*. Unless you can convince the author to re-implement command registration and keybinding assignment (or fork the package yourself), there's only one last resort: use the same dirty tricks to change the package's behaviour.

You can put the following CoffeeScript snippet in Atom's [init script](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/) file:

```coffee
# Get the selector for the atom-shortcuts element
atomShortCuts = document.querySelector "div.atom-shortcuts"

# Assign a custom keydown event
document.body.addEventListener 'keydown', (event) ->

  # Pick a shortcut, Ctrl+Shift+S in this example
  if event.ctrlKey and event.key is 'S'
    atomShortCuts.style.display = 'block'
  return
```

I recommend reading MDN's documentation for [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) if you want your keybinding to behave differently. CSS Tricks has a helpful [testing tool](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#article-header-id-0) for keyboard events.